The trait `borsh::de::BorshDeserialize` is not implemented for `T`
having this issue for the past 2 days with no way of resolving it..
Cargo.toml :
name = "mint-nft"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "mint_nft"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []

cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[profile.release]
overflow-checks = true

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.30.0"
mpl-token-metadata = { version="1.2.5", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ] }
anchor-spl = "0.30.0"
borsh-derive = "1.5.0"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }

Error : 

   Compiling mpl-token-metadata v1.13.1
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: borsh::de::BorshDeserialize` is not satisfied
   --> src/utils/mod.rs:176:21
    |
176 |     let result: T = try_from_slice_unchecked(data)?;
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `borsh::de::BorshDeserialize` is not implemented for `T`
    |
note: required by a bound in `solana_program::borsh::try_from_slice_unchecked`
   --> src/borsh.rs:39:1
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
167 | pub fn try_from_slice_checked<T: TokenMetadataAccount + borsh::de::BorshDeserialize>(
    |                                                       +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `mpl-token-metadata` (lib) due to previous error```


Command used : anchor build


Which solana version do you have installed? Solana --version

hello, version : solana-cli 1.18.8 (src:e2d34d37; feat:3469865029, client:SolanaLabs)

try remove the borsh and serde from the cargo.toml. Is it there for a reason?

By trying to debug this, i attempted a lot of desperate measures so that's why they are there, but removing them, still returns the same issue

Probably an old version of mpl-token-metadata. Best ask metaplex which version to use.

What does it mean to ask metaplex which version to use ? This is my first solana/rust project and i'm still kinda lost, I mostly followed a tutorial course and some documentation

Pretty sure this is because you're using anchor 0.30.0, which currently has a bug related to generics. On the github repo this has been fixed, so you have two options: 1. Use anchor 0.29.0. 2. Build anchor from source and use that. Since you mentioned this being your first project, I suggest going with 1.
